# Resize image returned by glReadPixels

Tags: c++, opengl

I have used `glReadPixels` to read pixels into an array. But the size of this image is a little big, so I want to resize it to a specific size. I cannot find an OpenGL function to resize the image. Does this kind of function exist, or I must write my own function to resize the image?

Note: the OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

This is the code to read image.

```
int img_w = 640; // screen size
int img_h = 480;
uint8_t img[img_w*img_h*3];
glReadPixels(0, 0, img_w, img_h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)img);

// NEW image size
int new_w = 140;
int new_h = 140;
uint8_t new_img[new_w*new_h*3];
// Is there some opengl function to resize the image in `img` like:
gl_some_resize_func(img, new_w, new_h, new_img);
```

Comment: I mean you probably heard that using `glReadPixels` is one of the slowest things that you can do in OpenGL and that you should avoid synchronously transfering memory from the GPU if at all possible. As for resizing, it would probably be faster if you rendered the image onto a smaller framebuffer with a fullscreen quad and then download the smaller amount of pixels.

Comment: @PeterT I really don't know an alternative to `glReadPixles`. Just learn opengl for 2 days... For resizing purpose, you mean I can create a new smaller framebuffer and throw the origin `img` above directly into this framebuffer(opengl will "resize" automatically?), then use the slow `glReadPixels` read from framebuffer?

Comment: If that tutorial teaches you to use `glReadPixels` (or `glBegin/glEnd`, etc) you should ditch that one and find a modern one for OpenGL 3+.  You are using a legacy functionality that was deprecated for years, and since you've just started learning OpenGL it's better you start learning the right way.

Comment: @ybungalobill: `glReadPixels` is not outdated, legacy, or "deprecated". It's a perfectly valid API; indeed, it's the only way to read from the default framebuffer on the CPU.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas It's valid but it's behavior outside of window connected to current  OpenGL context is actually undefined by standard. It may or may not to work. But all window system have others methods, simpler than to create OpenGL context. Oh, and it isn't frame buffer, it's  output, pixel buffer.

Comment: @Swift: "*Oh, and it isn't frame buffer, it's output, pixel buffer.*" There's no such thing as a "pixel buffer" in OpenGL. `glReadPixels` reads from the currently bound read framebuffer, which may be the default framebuffer or a user-defined FBO.

Comment: @PeterT This question is not about using something faster than `glReadPixels`.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas  There _are_ PBOs (https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Buffer_Object) as well a  FBO, it's an object for pixel operations and have no relation to FBO; it's the potential target for output in case of glreadpixels. I never saw working code with glReadPixels reading from bound FBO, though it is possible (as long as multisampling not enabled, it will cause invalid operation state), but it is a performance drop if two different render targets used, one just to get download.., it's better to read to PBO.

Answer (score -2):

No, there is not.  It would be a function of some image-processing library or your own, e.g. freeimage, openjpeg. OpenGL performs output of geometry to display, not operations with raster images.

It *is* possible _ to render image as texture, resample it using scale and filtering as read it again in abysmal quality, but that's not advised practice, for you always will have quality loss  compared to dedicated library. On mobile platforms in this case it will be also a component loss, because textures there currently supported in 16bit format. The only case when it  can be done is when you offload CPU or  require rendering to texture, which  actually done in different way.

Again, FreeImage, OpenJpeg, SDL or Qt provide  much better means for the task.

Comment: OpenGL is a rasterizer API and at least half of what it does is working with raster images, a.k.a textures, images and framebuffers. Resizing an image boils down to looping over the pixels of the smaller one and for each of them sampling the larger one at the correct locations with the correct filtering. And this **is** something that OpenGL supports and in fact really excels at.

Comment: In case you wonder what ybungalobill refers to: Drawing a textured quad. *However* (and this really must be said) the default minification and magnification filters are specified vaguely, so implementations have a lot of leeway in how they do it, so the resulting quality may vary a lot. If one needs very precise, reproducible and high quality filtering results, then sticking to a dedicated image processing library (which may be GPU accelerated and/or integrated with OpenGL) with well defined methods is preferable. Or implement your own filters (using OpenCL or compute shaders).

Comment: @datenwolf: Not only, there is `glBlitNamedFramebuffer` that does filtering and you can also run a compute shader with `imageLoad/Stores` without setting up a framebuffer at all. Also the default minification filter is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` and the default magnification is `GL_LINEAR`. It's exactly specified how both are computed, except for `glGenerateTextureMipmap` which you may or may not use.

Comment: @ybungalobill: What I meant by "specified vaguely" is, that the OpenGL specification defines very tight constraints on the algorithm which texels to select for filtering and how the filtering interpolation variables are to be evaluated. But it leaves some leeway on the precision of the mixing operation and how it interacts with dithering. These details are left open deliberately, to give implementors the wiggle room they need for their particular system architecture. And yes, the default interpolation method is specified, too.

Comment: @ybungalobill: However if you compare the filtering results of, say and AMD and a NVidia GPU, or even GPUs of the same vendor from different generations, or even with different driver setting (quality vs. precision settings) the differences can be quite noticeable. So if the desire is to obtain reproducible results, the built-in filtering methods are not the best choice.

Comment: @datenwolf in general you would need to that yourself anyway , just in shader code, algorithms used in OpenGL are quite basic and math precision is reduced compared to CPU. Real images we work with may have 128 bit per component, some GPUs limited to 10. Actually result not even unsteady but also have abysmal quality.OpenGL being rasterizer API doesn't mean that is image processing API.  you'll have decode, resize, capture, encode.. and get all those artifacts multiplied. There is proprietary lib that uses GPU for image processing, libKDU, and it got quite strange results on some adapters.

Comment: @Swift: That's exactly the point I was trying to get across here.

Comment: @datenwolf ah, ok, I misdomained that comment